# Unknown table name in VB.net using microsoft Access?

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if my subject isn't clear enough because I don't know how else to put. So here's the thing, I need to debug and test a VB.NET windows application for hotel management system. I'm quite new to VB.NET, so there is a few lines of database query that I didn't get. There is a few lines such as :

```
Com.CommandText = "Select * from QRoom Order by RoomNo"
```

or

```
Com.CommandText = "Select Floor from QRoom where RoomNo=" & cbo.Text & ""
```

as you can see the table name there is QRoom but when I check within the Access database, there is no table name QRoom. But if I change the table name to the one that us in the database(which is my case, it is TblRoom), then there will be errors. So I didn't get why is that. Any help is appreciated.

p/s : the guy who wrote this code is unreachable st the moment so I cannot directly ask him. :(

Comment: Well, if QRoom isn't in the database you will never be able to find it, but then _'there will be errors'_ is not very useful here. What is the exact error message?

Comment: ok now suddenly when I run the code it came out ok. Sorry about that. But before this when I change the table name to what it suppose to be, there will be error stating that there is "index out of bound" or something similar to that.

Comment: **Q** Room might not be a Table, but a **Q** uery? Have you checked if there are queries defined in your Access db?

Comment: I've already open the table design view, properties, etc. But I can't seem to find any query for that table. 

oh and here is the error if change to QRoom table to the actual name of the table within the database.
"No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: @ShahrulNizam: That error USUALLY means, that the column name doesn't exist. Would be another indicator that the Command is not meant to be run on a TABLE but on a QUERY. Another possiblity could be a **linked** table, though that should still be shown in Access (if the link cannot be fond an error is thrown on accessing that link)

Comment: ok thanks a lot man. I've found the queries. This is my first time using Microsoft Access so I don't really know that much about exploiting it. But what is the difference anyway??I mean what is the difference between executing a query from the database, and also executing a query to the database?And why is that when I change the table name, it detects it as doesn't exist??

(man i'm sorry if i ask too much questions. This is totally new to me and what I googled up isn't that much of a help either.)

Comment: There is no big difference. But dont forget that Access is not meant to be a database alone, but a complete system - able to show its own forms, reports etc. THEN you need to define your queries inside Access of course.

Comment: ohoo...but why is it if I change the table name in queries I post in my question above, instead of using queries,  I straight away put in a table name, just like a normal query, it will pop up an error saying that my table doesn't exist??